# JForm::getInstance could not load file

Tags: components, joomla3.0

I am making a form component into joomla.In which i will put one textbox and one editor and one button.
    i create the view file for this form and the component is successfully install.but when i click to display this form onto the front end,there is an error display like:

"The requested page cannot be found.
An error has occurred while processing your request.

You may not be able to visit this page because of:

an out-of-date bookmark/favourite
a mistyped address
a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site
you have no access to this page
Go to the Home Page

Home Page

If difficulties persist, please contact the System Administrator of this site and report the error below.

500 JForm::getInstance could not load file"
thanks for your support

Comment: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/2536 
Check this Link.

Comment: I will check my xml file there is no error.

Comment: You can mention what you did to solve it.. It will help others.

Comment: In my xml file (site/components/com_testimonial/models/forms/testimonial.xml) i mentioned "required" field two times.means there was an error in creating the form..

Comment: This happened to me because I forgot to include my XML folder in my initial XML file.

Answer (score 8):

**1. First check your form xml-file**

Front-end path: `components\com_<name_of_component>\models\forms\<formname>.xml`

Back-end path: `administrator\components\com_<name_of_component>\models\forms\<formname>.xml`

Example (Joomla 3.4.3): `administrator\components\com_users\models\forms\group.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <field name="id" type="hidden"
            default="0"
            required="true"
            readonly="true"
        />

        <field name="title" type="text"
            required="true"
            description="COM_USERS_GROUP_FIELD_TITLE_DESC"
            label="COM_USERS_GROUP_FIELD_TITLE_LABEL"
            size="40"
        />

        <field name="parent_id" type="groupparent"
            description="COM_USERS_GROUP_FIELD_PARENT_DESC"
            label="COM_USERS_GROUP_FIELD_PARENT_LABEL"
            required="true"
        />

        <field name="actions" type="hidden"
            multiple="true"
        />

        <field name="lft" type="hidden"
            filter="unset"
        />
        <field name="rgt" type="hidden"
            filter="unset"
        />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**2. Check your model class**

The method `getForm()` is responsible for loading the form (the form xml-file mentioned above).

Front-end path: `components\com_<name_of_component>\models\<modelname>.php`

Back-end path: `administrator\components\com_<name_of_component>\models\<modelname>.php`

Example (Joomla 3.4.3): `administrator\components\com_users\models\group.php`

```
/**
 * Method to get the record form.
 *
 * @param   array    $data      An optional array of data for the form to interogate.
 * @param   boolean  $loadData  True if the form is to load its own data (default case), false if not.
 *
 * @return  JForm   A JForm object on success, false on failure
 *
 * @since   1.6
 */
public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true)
{
    // Get the form.
    $form = $this->loadForm(
        'com_users.group', 
        'group', 
        array(
            'control' => 'jform', 
            'load_data' => $loadData)
        );

    if (empty($form))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return $form;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution in this question,I already mention in my question's comment that I got the answer for this.

Comment: You are welcome. For me the xml-file itself wasn't the problem (it was valid). I got the error because my getForm() method wasn't implemented the right way and so I added the post to give others the hint to have a look at their model containing the getForm() method.

Answer (score 0):

Check your xml file proper load and also check your view form add any extra xml form like (filter) then check it proper exists in models/forms folder